# match a path with string ignoring some part

Tags: java, string

I have path strings like /user/santosh/box/ or /user/ajay/box/

i like to match the path string with condition like /user/*/box/

```
     
    private static void matchValue(String value) {
        String match = "/Users/*/Box/";
        if(value.toLowerCase().contains(match.toLowerCase())) {
            System.out.println(value);
            System.out.println("Match Found");
        }
        
    }
```

I know above code does not work, I am just adding it for understanding, Is there anyway to achieve this.

Comment: Regular expressions can do this job. The web has a few million tutorials if you search for them, fortunately :) `Pattern.compile("^/Users/.*/Box/.*$")` perhaps - but read those tutorials, it's not a good idea to copy paste code that you do not understand.

Comment: You could also use the `startsWith` and `endsWith` methods from String class.